# Convert key columns to a JSON structure

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have this df:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data2 = [("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
  
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
df1.show(truncate=False)

+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|id   |gender|salary|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|James    |          |Smith   |36636|M     |3000  |
|Robert   |          |Williams|42114|M     |4000  |
|Maria    |Anne      |Jones   |39192|F     |4000  |
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
```

Then I have this df which is a metadata table with key fields in df1:

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
    (["firstname", "lastname"],["001", "002"])    ],
    ["col_lst", "id_lst"]
)

df2.show(truncate=False)

+---------------------+----------+
|col_lst              |id_lst    |
+---------------------+----------+
|[firstname, lastname]|[001, 002]|
+---------------------+----------+
```

I want to add a column to df1 one taking a combination of `(id, value)` from df2 in a JSON structure. Desired output:

```
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|id   |gender|salary|JSON                                                                            |
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|James    |          |Smith   |36636|M     |3000  |{"business_key":[{"id":"001","value":"James"},{"id":"002","value":"Smith"}]}    |
|Robert   |          |Williams|42114|M     |4000  |{"business_key":[{"id":"001","value":"Robert"},{"id":"002","value":"Williams"}]}|
|Maria    |Anne      |Jones   |39192|F     |4000  |{"business_key":[{"id":"001","value":"Maria"},{"id":"002","value":"Jones"}]}    |
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: are the values under `col_lst` always same or are they dynamic?

Comment: they are dynamic

Comment: How many rows do you have in df2?

Comment: one row in df2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array of structs from `df1.columns` then filter it using names from `df2.col_lst` and zip the result with `id_lst`. If you have few rows in `df2` it would simpler to collect them into variables and use it as literal expressions without having to cross join:

```
df3 = df1.crossJoin(df2).withColumn(
    "info",
    F.array(*[F.struct(F.lit(c).alias("k"), F.col(c).alias("v")) for c in df1.columns])
).withColumn(
    "JSON",
    F.to_json(
        F.struct(
            F.arrays_zip(
                F.col("id_lst").alias("id"),
                F.filter("info", lambda x: F.array_contains("col_lst", x["k"])).v.alias("value")
            ).alias("business_key")
        )
    )
).select(df1["*"], "JSON")

df3.show(truncate=False)

# +---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |firstname|middlename|lastname|id   |gender|salary|JSON                                                                            |
# +---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |James    |          |Smith   |36636|M     |3000  |{"business_key":[{"id":"001","value":"James"},{"id":"002","value":"Smith"}]}    |
# |Robert   |          |Williams|42114|M     |4000  |{"business_key":[{"id":"001","value":"Robert"},{"id":"002","value":"Williams"}]}|
# |Maria    |Anne      |Jones   |39192|F     |4000  |{"business_key":[{"id":"001","value":"Maria"},{"id":"002","value":"Jones"}]}    |
# +---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You need to change from ```k``` to ```v```in the array_contains property. And also the order of the ```arrays_zip``` to match exactly my desired output. Another brilliant solution. Merci!